# Find the length of the median of a trapezoid from the lengths of its diagonals?

Tags: geometry

> Is there a formula to find the length of the median of a trapezoid given the lengths of its diagonals?

Comment: How are the diagonals given?

Comment: They are just given as numbers

Comment: Note: OP has asked a more-specific version of this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1794727/409). By specifying that the diagonals are perpendicular (or, for that matter, that they make any given angle), the problem becomes solvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done.  Imagine the two diagonals as the blade/handles of a pair of scissors-- one diagonal goes from finger hole to point and the other goes from the finger hole of to the point of the other.  You can create different  trapezoids with many different lengths of sides and medians by opening or closing the scissors.

In other words you can have a triangle with diagonals of length $l_1$ and $l_2$ if the angle between them is small the median could be large.  You can have another trapezoids with diagonals of exactly the same length be a different angle, say a big angle, then the median would be a different value.

You might be able to do it if you know the diagonals and their intersecting angle.  But you might need to know their intersecting lengths as well.

Comment: What about this question: The diagonals of a trapezoid are perpendicular and have lengths 8 and 10. Find the length of the median of the trapezoid.

Comment: Pretend one diagonal is an x axis and the other is a y axis.  the mid point of one side is (x/2, y/2) and the midpoint of the other is ((x-8)/2, (y-2)/2)). So the median is $\frac 12 \sqrt{8^2 + 2^2}$ . THat's a formula:  1/2\sqrt{l1^2 + l2^2}.  For perpendicular only.

Comment: Please, don't ask new questions in comments. Post a new question, or edit the new question into the old one. But if fleablood has answered the question you actually posted here, accept her answer, and move on.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as can be seen in the figure.

You can have a base $CD$ of the trapezoid and with two diagonals of fixed lenghts you can form infinitely many trapezoids choosing distinct paralleles $AB$, $A'B'$,...... The corresponding medians will  generally be different.[image]

Comment: Nice diagram.  makes it very clear.

Comment: Also the diagram gives a hint that if we know the angle of the diagonals we probably can find a formula with angle and two lengths.